# python PIL ImageDraw

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\marple.jpg') 

input_text = 'Hey gys'
font = 'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Fira Code\\FiraCode-Regular.ttf' 
size = 100

colour = [1,2,3]
for i in range(0,3):
    colour[i] = int(input(f'Colour (RGB value {i + 1}) : '))
colour = tuple(colour)
type_text = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
type_text.text((0,0), input_text, font = font, fill = (255,0,0) )
image.show()
```

But when I  run this code it shows this error,

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 408, in draw_text
mask, offset = font.getmask2(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getmask2'
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Pillow Documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html):

You have to do
`font = ImageFont.truetype("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Fira Code\\FiraCode-Regular.ttf", 100)`.
The text module expects an ImageFont object, not a string.